# Stress testing of node.js services

Tags: javascript, node.js, load-testing, stress-testing

I'm building a stress testing framework for node.js services using node.js.

Do you know relevant projects which I can use / look at?
node.js projects that you've used and worked good? (latency, throughput etc..)

Any best practices on that matter?

Thanks!

Comment: I think that this question is not really a good fit for this Q&A format. It is quite localized and can potentially lead to subjective answers unless they are backed by solid benchmark results.

Comment: I disagree, i think it could direct me, and other people to good code refernces and methods which people have used and recommend

Comment: This question is relevant and would have helped me.

Comment: Why on earth is this too localized? Because it's about node? @Octavian what do you mean by 'being backed by solid benchmark results' - perhaps you thought this question was about relative performance of the framework? (it's not).

Comment: Well, apparently four other community members thought that the question as it was asked doesn't fit our format.

Comment: Why would you close this question?  Seems highly relevant.