# Moduls for stress testing of node.js services

Tags: javascript, node.js, load-testing, stress-testing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Stress testing of node.js services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8702560/stress-testing-of-node-js-services)

I'm want to build a stress testing framework for node.js services.

Do you know / have used node.js moduls which perform stress testing of node.js services? 
(which output throughput / latency etc.)

I looked at the toolbox site (http://toolbox.no.de/) and didn't find any good moduls that i can use / reference.

Thanks!

Comment: Closed as an exact duplicate?  @Octavian et al - you closed that one too! Are you going to reopen this one now? (since it's no longer a duplicate).

Comment: It's also not at all an 'exact duplicate'.  In this question he is asking specifically about node *modules*.

Comment: Good question - I was wondering the same thing myself.  Someone seems to have written a module for the job here: https://github.com/benschmaus/nodeload